# how to check if the user is in Stage channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

how to make the bot check if the user is in Stage channel?

I could not find information on this anywhere, I will be thankful for you if you help me

Comment: This feature hasn't even fulled rolled out yet. Thus, it's not implemented in discord.js by the time of writing this.

Comment: This feature has only been announced recently and has not been rolled out to all guilds yet, I'm sure there will be a post within the next few days explaining how to do this when this feature exists within discord.js.